# PHP strtotime seems to return an erroneous result for first week of the year (no comma)

Tags: php, time, php-5.6

This is the code I am using :

```
$date_format = "Y-W";

$date = date($date_format, strtotime("2019-3-25 - 11 week"));
echo($date.'<br/>');
$date = date($date_format, strtotime("2019-3-25 - 12 week"));
echo($date.'<br/>');
$date = date($date_format, strtotime("2019-3-25 - 13 week"));
echo($date.'<br/>');
```

This is what it returns (PHP 5.6.36) :

```
2019-02

2018-01

2018-52
```

The first and last result look correct, the middle one doesn't, do you know how to correct this ?

Comment: What would you have *expected* for the second result…?

Comment: @deceze 2019-01 not 2018-01

Comment: You may want to look at the options available for [`date`](http://php.net/date): *"`o` - ISO-8601 week-numbering year. This has the same value as Y, except that if the ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year, that year is used instead. (added in PHP 5.1.0)"*

Comment: maybe its due to 31st Dec, because `W` starting from monday and 31st == monday

Comment: @deceze Oh my god it must be that, what a strange way to arrange the weeks, thank you very much for your insight

Comment: Well, since week and year boundaries seldom align, that's a whole thing you may want to learn about… https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates

Comment: @deceze Sure, but then having a week 2018-53 would be a far less confusing option than calling it the 2018-01 week.. There might be years where the same year have two weeks marked -01 week (if the year begins on monday). Plus the missing -01 week for most years.

It s just my opinion, but I find that very misleading and I would qualify that as a poor design choice.

Comment: Well, there's a difference between the *ISO-8601 week-numbering year* and the actual year. If you mix week numbers and years together, you may get weird results. If you use week numbers with the *ISO-8601 week-numbering year*, then it's all good. There can't be *one correct* answer, since again, the problem is a fundamental misalignment between week and year boundaries. ISO-8601 has defined *a* solution, and if we all stick to that, all is well.